# How to add a legend to a figure

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, legend, figure

I would like to add a legend into my figure. This is the code i used to print the plot:

```
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.legend("Test Legend")
ax1.plot(singleColumn)
```

This is the plot i get:
[fig1 plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fYTa.png)

If i use this code:

```
print(singleColumn.plot(legend=True))
```

[Perfect Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JJ74.png)

I will get a perfect plot with a legend, but if i plot other figures, all plots are mixed up, so i would prefer the fig method.

How i add the Name of the Data into the fig1 plot ?

Best regards
Kai

edit:
The sinmgleColumn looks like that, i displayed the head:

```
[5 rows x 13 columns]
MESSDATUM
2011-01-10    2.40
2011-02-02    2.17
2011-03-03    2.32
2011-04-06    1.67
2011-05-04    2.56
Name: 2433876, dtype: float64
```

Comment: how does your `singleColumn` look like?

Comment: try hits:`ax1.plot(df.MESSDATUM, df.value, label='Test Legend');ax1.legend()`